# MySQL: Return user making over X requests in Y amount of time

Tags: mysql, sql

If I had a list of users coming back from my DB, is it possible to filter out and return the user(s) that appear over X amount of times in Y amount of time?

Here's an example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM user_activity;
+----------+---------------------+
| username | created_at          |
+----------+---------------------+
| User A   | 2018-12-06 00:00:00 |
| User B   | 2018-12-06 00:00:00 |
| User B   | 2018-12-06 00:09:00 |
| User A   | 2018-12-06 00:11:00 |
+----------+---------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00sec)
```

In MySQL, How would I return `User B` because this user appears more than once in a 10minute period? `User A` would be omitted from this result because they only appear once every 10minutes.

Comment: The condition where y > 1is simpler than where y = n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an aggregate query, with a `HAVING` clause to filters users based on their number of occurences. The filter on the date goes to the `WHERE` clause.

The folowing query selects all users having at least 2 entries within 10 minutes after the given `@report_date` :

```
set @report_date = "2018-12-06 00:00:00";

SELECT username
FROM user_activity
WHERE created_at 
    BETWEEN DATE_ADD(@report_date, INTERVAL 10 MINUTE) 
    AND @report_date
GROUP BY username
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT a.username
FROM
    user_activity a
    INNER JOIN user_activity b ON (
            b.username = a.username
        AND b.created_at > a.created_at
        AND b.created_at <= DATE_ADD(a.created_at, INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)
    )
```

Comment: So this is working but can you please add an explanation as to why and what is going on? Will this work if I continue to add users as time goes on?

Comment: I think the query is very self-explaining: simple self-join with additional condition. Joining record should be withing specific time interval. Do not know what else should I add to the explanation. Oh, one more thing: multi-column index (username, created_at) is highly recommended.

Answer (score 0):

I would think about using `exists`:

select ua.*

```
from user_activity ua
where (select count(*)
       from user_activity ua2
       where ua2.user_name = ua.user_name and
             ua2.created_at <= ua.created_at and
             ua2.created_at > ua.created_at - interval 10 minute
      ) > 1;
```

This method is flexible.  Your question is generally about having `n` occurrences during a period.  Normally, I advocate using `exists` when someone wants a single occurrence, but for the general question, `count(*)` is a respectable approach.